Rails JavaScript works fine only with direct URL
In my application I use javascript to manage the fields in the form. When I visit the website by entering the address directly in the browser eg http://IP:3000/admin/systems/new, the javascript scripts works fine. However, when I call this page from the menu, the scripts don't work. After refreshing the page, the scripts work again.
I tried putting the scripts directly into the .html.erb file instead of application.js, hoping it would load every time, but it didn't.
One of my javascript
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        var optionSelect = document.getElementById('option-select');
        var dateInput1 = document.getElementById('date-input1');
        var dateInput2 = document.getElementById('date-input2');

        optionSelect.addEventListener('change', function() {
                if (optionSelect.value === '1') {
                        dateInput1.removeAttribute('readonly');
                        dateInput2.removeAttribute('readonly');
                        dateInput1.style.backgroundColor = '';
                        dateInput2.style.backgroundColor = '';
                } else {
                        dateInput1.setAttribute('readonly', true);
                        dateInput2.setAttribute('readonly', true);
                        dateInput1.style.backgroundColor = '#fbfbfe';
                        dateInput2.style.backgroundColor = '#fbfbfe';
                }
        });

        if (optionSelect.value === '') {
                dateInput1.setAttribute('readonly', true);
                dateInput2.setAttribute('readonly', true);
                dateInput1.style.backgroundColor = '#fbfbfe';
                dateInput2.style.backgroundColor = '#fbfbfe';

        }
});

application.js
import "@hotwired/turbo-rails"
import "./controllers"
import * as bootstrap from "bootstrap"
import "./select"
import "./working"

Menu link
<li class="nav-item dropdown">
              <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                Systems
              </a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="<%= new_admin_system_path %>">Add system</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="<%= admin_systems_path %>">List</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>

How can I make it work also when I go to a page with a menu?

https://turbo.hotwired.dev/handbook/building#installing-javascript-behavior

@Alex thanks for the direction. I changed DOMContentLoaded to turbo:load and it still works strange. When I add my scritps to application.js it works fine but it throws errors in views where individual scripts are not used like  "TypeError: optionSelect is null". But if I if I throw away the scripts and place them in a specific view using <%= javascript_include_tag 'select.js' %> after logging in to the application and selecting an option from the menu for the first time, the script does not execute, only selecting the option for the second and next time starts the script. What is wrong?

once the script is loaded, it stays loaded even if you navigate to a different page, that's how Turbo works, it doesn't perform a full page reload. also, you're adding a "change" event listener on every navigation, which accumulate on every page navigation. you should use "event delegation" https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#event_delegation. not sure about the second issue, race conditions maybe. but i'd use a Stimulus controller for this anyway.

@Alex so how can I debug this second issue (dev tools in browser says nothing) or avoid errors like "TypeError: optionSelect is null"?

@Alex ok, so going back to loading scripts using application.js and handling event delegation solved the problem, thanks for the direction.
